# ImportError: No module named tflearn

Tags: python, bash, python-import

Above Error comes only when i am trying to run the script :  `"rgarg:pytutorial raghav$ python tflearn11.py"`

It working fine in Rodeo IDE, also if I put `"import tflearn "` in command line python interpreter it works fine (even I typed full script in command line , it worked fine w/o import issue) .

My packages are in same location as i have given in my bash (Mac OS El Captain)

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

A similar problem i found [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810996/5947775) but not getting how can i remove path(0) when running from python interpreter.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you developing this inside a virtual environment?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist : may be i can use later on but i am just now in nascent stage of learning , I don't understand what i am doing wrong,  script works fine on RODEO , It work fine when I put everything on command line python interpreter  , but just simply doesn't work while i run using : python script.py
can you please help what i am missing.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Virtual environments make it **easier** to manage dependencies without breaking your system. They are not something to be avoided at any stage of learning and they are not hard. If you install this in a virtual environment, your path will be managed automatically and this problem will likely evaporate with no chance of you breaking your system. Instead, you're trying to solve it manually in a way that could render some systems inoperable if you do it wrong -- **not** the beginner-friendly approach!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist , Thanks , it worked finally in virtual environment . But one thing i will mention that we should use sudo easy_install virtualenv (then only it will create exec file in usr/local/bin) , if we use pip install virtualenv it will not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Two-Bit mentioned i used virtualenvs [Link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

But please make sure use below for installation of virtualenvs

*$ sudo easy_install virtualenvs*

instead of pip install virtualenvs.