# ImportError: No module named <<MyPackage>>

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

```
adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package/web$ cat myscript.py 
from package.settings import sth
adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package/web$ python myscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package.settings import sth
ImportError: No module named package.settings
adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package/web$ python3 myscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package.settings import sth
ImportError: No module named 'package'

adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package$ ls
__init__.py  settings  web 
adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package$ cd web 
adam@adam:~/Untitled Folder/package/web$ ls 
myscript.py  __init__.py
```

How do I run that, then? I tried to run it from every folder (up to the `Untitled Folder`) with no success. In pycharm it works.

Comment: Have you done a pip install for flaskapp.py?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case but you may have forgotten to install the module. This can be done by:

1.) Installing python-pip if you haven't done so yet:

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

2.) Run pip to install your packages (Not sure how pip refers to it as):

```
pip install <package>
```

Another thing to check out is applying your project in your Python Path. [ImportError: No module named package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782478/importerror-no-module-named-package)

Comment: it's my script `cat flaskapp.py 
from package.settings import sth`, I should rename it in the question to reduce the confusion

Comment: Ahh ok i understand.. I just modified my answer. I would check and confirm if you have the packages the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: The example shall be without any third party packages