# ImportError: No module named ****

Tags: python, import

I am aware that `__init__.py` is needed for imports and to make python treat folder as package.

Below is my directory structure

```
init_stuffs/
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── new_pack
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── animal.py
    ├── animal.pyc
    ├── bird.py
    ├── bird.pyc
    └── common.py
```

When i `cd` in the directory and try to run my `common.py` i get below error

```
(robo-fm) ~/Desktop/python_code/init_stuffs/new_pack $ python common.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "common.py", line 6, in <module>
    from new_pack import xinit
ImportError: No module named new_pack
```

but below works fine :

```
(robo-fm) ~/Desktop/python_code/init_stuffs $ python -m new_pack.common

 i am a bird class

 i am a bird

 i am in animal class

 i am a lion

 i am a bird class

 i am a bird

 i am in animal class

 i am a lion
('x=', 5)
```

checked this thread as well [ImportError: No module named package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782478/importerror-no-module-named-package), but no help

**common.py**

```
import sys
# import os
# sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))

# print sys.path
from new_pack import xinit 
from bird import bird 
from animal import animal 

x=bird()
x.sparrow()
y=animal()
y.lion()
print("x=",xinit)
```

**__init__.py**

```
# print("\n hi i am __init__")
xinit=5
```

I am on python2.7

**Question**

how can i run `common.py` as file rather than running it as part of module using `-m`?

TIA